# JSF2 i18n bean validation messages

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, bean-validation

How can I return a i18n localized bean validation message?

For example, in:

```
@Size(min = 1, message = "{pleaseProvideADescription}")
private String description;
```

Even though I set  properties file in faces-config.xml, and I include a pleaseProvideADescription=Please provide a...

I'm still getting:

{pleaseProvideADescription}

As validation message in  tag

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Bean validation ([JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)) is completely unrelated to JSF2 ([JSR-314](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314)). It's *another* part of standard Java EE API.

The validation messages have to go in a file named `ValidationMessages.properties` in the classpath root (which you can internationalize with `ValidationMessages_xx_XX.properties` files).

Put your custom message there. You don't need to configure anything in JSF's `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: "Bean validation (JSR-303) is completely unrelated to JSF2 (JSR-314). It's another part of standard Java EE API." But which locale would be used in this case - I assume the server locale? This wouldn't be the one which we need...

Comment: I followed your hint and added the messages into a property file. Without success. [you can see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280800/how-does-it-work-with-bean-validation-messages-and-i18n-in-jsf2)