# Custom bean validation does not `@inject` CDI beans and does not interpolate message?

Tags: cdi, bean-validation, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am using GF4 with bean validation. I am trying to `@Inject` a service bean in my custom validator but I get a `null` value.

```
 public class TestValidator implements ConstraintValidator<>{
   @Inject Service myService;
}
```

Isn't this suppose to be working with JEE7?

Also, I am trying to find built-in dynamic message interpolation (Without writing my own `MessageInterpolator`). I did see some examples but they are not very clear. What I am looking for is to pass dynamic parameters from the `ConstraintValidator.isValid`. For example:

> Message_test={value} is not valid

And somehow weave this, in the same way that you can statically interpolate the `Annotation` values e.g. size_msg={min}-{max} is out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dependency injection into validators should be possible with Java EE 7 / Bean Validation 1.1 in general.

How do you perform validation and how do you obtain a `Validator` object? Note that DI only works by default for container-managed validators, i.e. those you retrieve via `@Inject` or a JNDI look-up. If you bootstrap a validator yourself using the BV bootstrap API, this validator won't be CDI-enabled.

Regarding message interpolation, you can refer to the validated value using `${validatedValue}`. If you're working with Hibernate Validator 5.1.0.Alpha1 or later, then you also have [the possibility](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-hibernateconstraintvalidatorcontext) to add more objects to the message context from within `ConstraintValidator#isValid()` like this:

```
public boolean isValid(Date value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    Date now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime();

    if ( value.before( now ) ) {
        HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext =
                context.unwrap( HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class );

        hibernateContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        hibernateContext.addExpressionVariable( "now", now )
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "Must be after ${now}" )
                .addConstraintViolation();

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using `@Named
@ApplicationScoped` to define my services. Validation is triggered through JSF 2.2, so I assume it would be loaded via CDI. Inside my validator, I am using `@Inject` to reference my service bean.

As far as hibernate is concerned, I wouldn't like to couple my application to any implementation.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. If the Validation annotation is set on a JSF bean, then the service is injected properly. If validation annotation is set on the JPA bean, then it is not. I assume this is normal because the services are defined as `@Named/@ApplicationScoped` so they are not available in the hibernate CDI context.