# EJB injection fails in custom ConstraintValidator on JPA persist

Tags: jpa, ejb, cdi, bean-validation, java-ee-7

I have a problem with my JSF/JPA/Bean Validation app. Custom constraints annotating (JPA) entity fields don’t function correctly on JPA pre-persist although they work fine during JSF form validation

**Environment:**
NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 / GlassFish Server 4.1
JPA 2.1/EJB 3.2 /CDI 1.1/BeanValidation 1.1 /Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
cdi-api.jar added to ejb/web projects as it seems it was missing.

**Problem**
My App contains a JSF 2.2 page whose backing/CDI bean (Register) contains references to fields of (JPA) entities on the server/EJB tier. The entities are annotated with constraint annotations, and during the form filling, the validation works fine. I think this is a fairly standard setup with a @Named(CDI) bean as the backing(controller) bean.

I have custom constraints (@UserName and @Email) that check username and email is unique. Again these are EJB validators, and inject an EJB service which is used to check if username/email is in the DB using JPQL. Again this works fine when the form itself is being validated, and the form action will not be called if either of these validations fails.

The problem starts when form validation is successful and the CDI bean makes the call to the ejb service to add the new entity.  In the log I see;

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
………………
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nick.bookstore.validators.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:40)
```

(See attached logs)

And I am able to see that the injected LoginService in the EmailValidator is null.
EmailValidator uses LoginService:

```
 @Inject 
 private LoginService loginService;
```

– so injection failed, and this causes a null pointer exception.

So when validation is invoked from the CDI bean – it works, when managed by JPA it fails.

I have seen a similar problem  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161837/custom-bean-validation-does-not-inject-cdi-beans-and-does-not-interpolate-mes) but this does not answer my question.

I have written a JUnit test that invokes the EJB service to persist a entity(customer) directly and this confirms the error detailed above.

Any help on understanding what is happening here is appreciated.

**BookStoreProcessingBean(ejb)**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean

public class BookStoreProcessingBean {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "BookStorePU")
    private EntityManager em;
….
 public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
                        em.persist(customer);
     } 
}
```

Entities; **Person** -> Extended by **Customer**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="Type")
public  class Person implements Serializable { 

    public Person(Address homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }
……..    
   @Basic
   @Email
   @NotNull(message = "Email field must have a value")
   private String email;

……
}

@Entity
public  class Customer extends Person implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    private SecurityDetails securityDetails;
…….
}
```

Validators; **@Email** and **@UserName**

```
public class EmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Email, String> {

    @Inject 
    private LoginService loginService;


    @Override
    public void initialize(Email constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //First check for a valid pattern and then for existence in DB       
........         
       return !loginService.emailAlreadyExists(email); //Failure here as loginService is null
    }



public class UserNameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserName, String> {

    @Inject
    private LoginService loginService;

    public UserNameValidator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(UserName constraintAnnotation)   
    }  
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String userName, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean unAlreadyExists = loginService.userNameAlreadyExists(userName);
        return !unAlreadyExists; 
    }
```

**Log Output**

```
    Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB BookStoreProcessingBean, method: public void com.nick.bookstore.ejb.BookStoreProcessingBean.addCustomer(com.nick.bookstore.entities.Customer)
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy305.addCustomer(Unknown Source)
    at com.nick.bookstore.ejb.__EJB31_Generated__BookStoreProcessingBean__Intf____Bean__.addCustomer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:414)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.nick.bookstore.ejb.BookStoreProcessingBean$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.addCustomer(Unknown Source)
    at com.nick.bookstore.beans.Register.register(Register.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4293)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at com.nick.bookstore.ejb.BookStoreProcessingBean.addCustomer(BookStoreProcessingBean.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nick.bookstore.validators.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:43)
    at com.nick.bookstore.validators.EmailValidator.isValid(EmailValidator.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:281)
    ... 111 more
```

Comment: The problem here is related to which environment is loading the valIdator. Cdi can inject the service but the ejb container cannot. Either use beanmanager directly to lookup the service or find away to make your validator an ejb session bean

Comment: No answer to your question, just a quick thought: I would not use Bean Validators for calling services. You should define the valid format of user names (max 8 letters, starting with lowercase letter, ...) but use real real service methods (and calls) to evaluate existence of users. Why? because the userName will not only be used in your service application, but also in a UI for example. it will be used in parts of your system (or remote systems via api)  where you do not have your LoginService injectable ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @maress - Yse, it seems that the JPA implementation loads the validator and does not support injection. I still want to check if this is actually by designr if it's optional. Certailnle a custom validator factory will solve the problem but this may not be portable - I'll get back on that.

Comment: @Jan Galinski - Thanks. I wanted to see what is possible, what should work out of the box. The fact that a JSF backing bean  (a '@named', CDI compoent) will suport injection and then JPA will _not_ apprears a little inconsistent, especially considering that the validators are defined on the JPA entity itself. I will investigate further and report back on this question. I do agree that where client is not JSF(or equivalen, performing validation on the server) that injection would not be possible - but it was nice to see this beanvalidation showing up correctly on the JSF page form.

Comment: @NickJI yes, currently jpa validators do not support injection. What i normally do is to do a manual lookup of an ejb session bean where i do all the injections and delegate to appropriately registered validator